# Is the infimum on a numerable union of sets less or equal than the sum of the infimum on the sets?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given $A= \bigcup_\limits{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i $ and given a *'proposition'* (voluntary vague) of which we want to evaluate the infimum, is it true that

$\displaystyle{\text{inf}_{A} \leq \sum_\limits{i \in \mathbb{N}}\text{inf}_{A_i}} \ \ \ \ \ \Large{?}$

I want to restrict to the case in which every infimum is at least $0$.

For example, the *proposition* can be a function, or also the interval-coverings of $A$, as in the Lebesgue measure (on which this proposition is true).

Comment: I think $\inf_A$ would equal $\inf\{\inf_{A_i}\mid i\in\Bbb N\}$

Comment: I think this question is weird because the term "proposition" conflates too many things which are inherently different.  The infimum of a function over a set $A$ is very different than the infimum of lengths over the *set of all coverings* of $A$.